# Asignar un nuevo valor a la variable tipo arreglo de char (string) concatenando un caracter a la variable

Tags: array, c

Tengo esta situación.
Hay una variable de tipo arreglo de char (string). Lo que necesito haces es concatenar un caracter a esa variable y el resultado asignarlo a la misma variable.
En pseudocódigo sería así:
`hex <- 0 + hex`
Aquí el código:

```
if (value) {
    char hex[10];
    if (total > 0) {
        while (total > 0) {
            int mod = (int) total % 16;
            total = total / 16;
            switch (mod) {
            case 0:
                hex = "0" + hex; //hex <- "0" + hex
                break;
            case 1:
                hex = "1" + hex;
                break;
            case 2:
                hex = "2" + hex;
                break;
            case 3:
            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: [Buscas esto?](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat)

Comment: Si, pero ¿cómo se implementa en el código?

Comment: En el link tienes ejemplos de como se usa.

Comment: Pero eso es otro código

Comment: Tu pregunta es como se contatenan los strings. De aqui en
adelante te toca aplicar. Aqui no te van a hacer la tarea, si
quieres aprender a programar tienes que aprender a hacer las
cosas por tu cuenta.

Comment: No todos los códigos son iguales

Comment: Eso que significa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que pretendes es añadir caracteres **al principio** de una cadena.

Es simple: mueves la cadena ya existente N posiciones a la derecha. Ten en cuenta que en esta operación ambas posiciones (la antigua y la nueva) comparten espacio (hay *overlap*), por lo que no puedes usar ciertas funciones, como, por ejemplo, [`strcpy( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) ni [`strncpy( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy). Ambas incurren en *comportamiento indefinido* si las zonas origen/destino se solapan.

Podrías usar las versiones `_s` (seguras), disponibles a partir de C11.

En su defecto, también puedes usar [`memmove( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove):

```
if( value ) {
    char hex[10] = { 0 }; // Rellenamos con 0
    if( total > 0 ) {
        while( total > 0 ) {
            int mod = (int) total % 16;
            total = total / 16;
            switch( mod ) {
            case 0:
                memmove( hex + 1, hex, strlen( hex ) );
                *hex = '0';
                break;

            case 1:
                memmove( hex + 1, hex, strlen( hex ) );
                *hex = '1';
                break;

            case 2:
                memmove( hex + 1, hex, strlen( hex ) );
                *hex = '2';
                break;
            case 3:
            .
            .
            .
```

Observa que solo estamos desplazando 1 posición a la derecha, y que estamos añadiendo solo **caracteres individuales**.
Tampoco estamos comprobando que nos pasemos de tamaño de `hex`.
Y, por último, esto solo funciona si `hex` contiene siempre una cadena C estándar, terminada por un *byte* `0` (para que `strlen( )` funcione ).

Comment: Dale, lo pruebo